# changing attribute value on validation class in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation

How can we change attribute values on validation classes in laravel ?
consider this code:

```
class Twice implements Rule
{ 
  public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        $value = $value * 2;
        return $value > 20;
    }
}
```

and now we receive value multiply by 2 in score attribute:

```
$rules = [
'score' => [new Twice]
]
```

if we can't, what is your suggestion ?

Comment: Are you wanting to return `$value * 2` from the validator if it passes?

Comment: yes, exactly  :)

Comment: It is a validation rule not a data processor. You can change your data after you get it anywhere you like!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`prepareForValidation`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#preparing-input-for-validation) method in a validator class:

```
protected function prepareForValidation()
{
    $this->merge([
        'score' => $this->score * 2
    ]);
}
```

This will change the value of `score` to `score * 2` and use that value for any validation, and also return that value with your request data.

Doing this, you also won't need it in the `passes` method on your Rule since the `score` passed in will already be multiplied by 2:

```
public function passes($attribute, $value)
{
    return $value > 20;
}
```

Or you could even skip the custom rule altogether at that point and use:

```
$rules = [
    'score' => 'min:21'
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually we are trying to migrate our huge application from yii2 to laravel.

In yii2 framework we made some rule classes that tweak data before inserting to database, for example "ConverToEnglishNumber" which convert "Persian" numbers (۱۲۳۴۵) into "English" numbers (12345).

```
public function rules()
{
  return [
    ['content', ConverToEnglishNumber::class]
  ]
}
```

but it seem impossible in laravel validation rules classe.
after a struggling day, I think using casts is the best way to do that:

```
namespase App\Casts;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Database\Eloquent\CastsAttributes;

class Double implements CastsAttributes
{
    public function set($model, $key, $value, $attributes)
    {
        return $value * 2;
    }
}
```

```
namespace App\Models;

use App\Casts\Double;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Player extends Model
{
  protected $casts = [
    'score' => Double::class
  ];
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you've already got something working for you, but for that kind of scenario you can also use the setters on the model. Something like `public function setScoreAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['score'] = $value * 2;
}` -- doing this will set the score to $value * 2 when it's saved. Note that it will do that *every time* it's saved, which you will need to account for.

Comment: Yes, thank you a lot,  using setters is another way to doing that, but it's not reusable.
we want to be used in many where